# react-native-ios xcode Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID

Tags: ios, react-native-ios

Newbie question here, I was trying to run react-native run-ios this message just popped up. I fixed the other problem though, with the versions on build but this message is still poping up and build did fail.

User defaults from command line:
    IDEDerivedDataPathOverride = /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project

note: Using new build system
note: Planning build
note: Using build description from disk
warning: Capabilities for Signing & Capabilities may not function correctly because its entitlements use a placeholder team ID. To resolve this, select a development team in the project editor. (in target 'project' from project 'project')
PhaseScriptExecution Start\ Packager /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    cd /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios
    /bin/sh -c /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Intermediates.noindex/project.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.build/Script-FD10A7F022414F080027D42C.sh
Connection to localhost port 8081 [tcp/sunproxyadmin] succeeded!

CpResource /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Thin.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/Montserrat-Thin.otf (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    cd /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Thin.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app

CpResource /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/Montserrat-SemiBold.otf (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    cd /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-SemiBold.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app

CpResource /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/Raleway-Bold.ttf (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    cd /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app
error: /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf: No such file or directory (in target 'project' from project 'project')

CpResource /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/Montserrat-Regular.otf (in target 'project' from project 'project')
    cd /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios
    builtin-copy -exclude .DS_Store -exclude CVS -exclude .svn -exclude .git -exclude .hg -resolve-src-symlinks /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.otf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app

** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CpResource /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf /Users/dariocruzminozajr./Projects/SunBeam/cleaning-solution-frontend/project/ios/build/project/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/project.app/Raleway-Bold.ttf
(1 failure)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your font file "Raleway-Bold.ttf" is not linked properly.

if React Native Version ≥ 0.60

Step 1:Create File “react-native.config.js” and add following code

```
`module.exports = {
project: {
 ios: {},
 android: {},
},
assets: ["./assets/fonts/"], // stays the same
};`
```

Step 2: Link assets using react native link
`react-native link`

Step 3: Check "Resource" folder in xcode project.
Your font file should be in Resource folder.

Above issue generates when your resources are not linked to your project.

You can check steps on below link:
https://medium.com/@mehran.khan/ultimate-guide-to-use-custom-fonts-in-react-native-77fcdf859cf4